# How to add these crooked lines and the value labels to a doughnut chart in react-chartjs2?

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

[image: doughnut graph made using react-chartjs2]

[image: doughnut graph that I have made using react-chartjs2]

Image 01 is the one I need to make, while Image 02 is the one I've currently implemented. Notice the difference between the two. I need to implement the two crooked lines and the value labels associated with them. These lines and the positioning of these values isn't going to be static since the two values in the doughnut graph chart is going to be different every time.

I've tried searching online but I couldn't find a solution to this.